# R igraph: Replacing node names, adding attributes

Tags: r, attributes, igraph

I have following sample for a graph in R igraph:

```
# Erdos
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1/100)
V(g)$size<-seq(0.05,1,0.05)

# Draw nodes and save positions
locs <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(g, layout=locs, vertex.label=NA, main="Original")

# Show igraph data
g
```

Generally, I like to know how

1. The current node names can be replaced with new ones and
2. How this can be combined with adding new node information.

This is how the dataframe with the new information looks like:

```
     node_old  node_new  Type  More_Data
1    5         1         AA    122.5
2    2         2         BB    80.4
3    12        3         CC    104.3
```

"Type" and "More_Data" are the information that I like to assign to the nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: You can assign a variable to the nodes the exact same way you assigned a size attribute to the nodes in your example: `V(g)$Type <- df$Type` etc.

Comment: Please clarify a bit: Do you want the 5th node renamed 1, the second to remain 2, the third node renamed 12, etc?

Answer (score 0):

if '5' is node name, then

```
V(g)$label[V(g)$label=='5'] <- '1'
V(g)$Type[V(g)$label=='5'] <- 'AA'
V(g)$More_Data[V(g)$label=='5'] <- 122.5
```

if '5' is 5th node,

```
V(g)$Type[5] <- 'AA'
V(g)$More_Data[5] <- 122.5
```